# screenshots of failed katalon testcases in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, katalon

I'm an intern and have recieved this task. Sadly I'm completely lost and cannot solve it on my own:
How to take screenshots of failed testcases in Katalon, but save them in Jenkins?  When saved, how exactly do I open them? A further helpfull thing would be to know how to create a ticket in Jira when a testcase fails and attatch the screenshot with the fail message.

I tryed WebUI.screenschot(path) but niether do I know which exact path to give for Jenkins, nor how to extract the Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`WebUI.takeScreenshot()` (without path argument) should save screenshot in the current working folder.

After that, you need to go to Jenkins to fetch the screenshot, but the specifics will vary depending on the setup.